# Naming Context stop working after idle time JBoss EAP 6.4.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I am using JBoss EAP 6.4 to deploy an EJB ear file. Everything works fine but if Swing application idle for some time(1 hour or so) and then try to access any feature from swing client, client got crashed with below exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to invoke lookup, status=WAITING
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.execute(Protocol.java:98)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingStoreV1.lookup(RemoteNamingStoreV1.java:95)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore$1.operation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:275)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:132)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:271)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookupInternal(RemoteContext.java:104)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:93)
     at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:146)
     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
```

It does not able to resolve jndi with cached context at client side.

Context created in client using below properties:

```
    table.put("remote.connection.one.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
                    table.put("remote.connection.one.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");

table.put("remote.clusters", "ejb");
                    table.put("remote.cluster.ejb.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
table.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
table.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
                    table.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
    table.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, System.getProperty( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL));
    table.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, System.getProperty( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS));
                    table.put("jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED","true");
                    table.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS","true");
    table.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.timeout", "3000000");
    table.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL,PROVIDER_URL);

    context = new javax.naming.InitialContext( table);
```

Please help me to understand why after an idle time context is not able to lookup?

Comment: Try create the context every time,  second you need to close context if you finish with it. Dont reuse the proxy.

Comment: Could you please provide me more details about 'Don't reuse the proxy'? also will it not impact the performance?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092379/caching-remote-ejb-3-0-reference

Comment: will it be an issue if JBoss client properties are configured manually? We can not recreate context every time because of existing application architecture. Most of the time context stop responding exact after 60 min of ideal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. In JBoss EAP 6.4 using old JNDI approach creates issues and does not support JBoss features like HeartBeat_Interval etc.

Best way to lookup in Jboss is to use EJB Client lookup approch. This solves all issues related to crash etc.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project